# Custom Number Field is not executing "to_python"?

Tags: django, encryption, python-2.7, django-models

I am new to Django and Python.

In my project I am using CustomField defined by me so that I can encrypt the data values before storing into database and decrypt it after retreiving (there is need for encryption in my case).

I have gone through git-repository / stackoverflow / google to find the answer for my question, there are similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them got this issue. As I am unable to fix it from 2 days, would certainly need help now.

I have the code which is defining CustomField as follows -

```
def get_multiple_of_8(some_value):
some_value = str(some_value)
while(len(some_value) % 8 != 0):
    some_value = '0'+some_value
return some_value

def is_multiple_of_8(input_str):
    input_str = str(input_str)
    if(len(input_str) % 8 == 0):
        return True
    return False

class CustomField(models.Field):
    '''To Encrypt the values in Model'''
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.key = myProject.settings.SECRET_KEY[:8]
        self.des = DES.new(self.key, DES.MODE_ECB)
        kwargs['max_length'] = kwargs.get('max_length',128)
        models.Field.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'CharField'

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None

        value = "%.2f" % value
        value = get_multiple_of_8(value)

        to_return = self.des.encrypt(value)
        to_return = to_return.decode('latin-1')
   #    to_return = force_unicode(to_return)
        return to_return

     def to_python(self, value):
        value = value.encode('latin-1')
        if is_multiple_of_8(value):
            to_return = self.des.decrypt(value)
        try:
            to_return = float(to_return)
            return to_return
        except:
            return 0
```

Encryption works perfectly, I can see the encrypted field values using sqlite3 command line.

error I am getting is :

Exception Type: InvalidOperation
Exception Value: Invalid literal for Decimal: '\xc3\x85\xc3\x84\xc3\xa13\xc2\xa6\x0f(u'

On debugging found that "to_python()" is not functioning properly. (Code source from django-fields git). I am getting error which shows encrypted string on screen instead of actual value upon retrieval through views.py !

I found one question on stackoverflow having same problem but got fixed because of **metaclass** syntax in different Python version.
My Python version 2.7.5 and Django 1.4.5, I am developing site on Windows 7.

Please someone help me resolve the issue, also Is there a way to debug these kind of issues ?, any suggestion is accepted, thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer :)

Had to understand how the SQLite database system works!

The problem here is, when the Database which we are using, let it be any in that case. Firstly we shall format the data to be stored into it. Once the types are assigned to the database table fields, (I don't know why) still it can save data of other format (May be bug in SQLite, table had Integer field but still stored 350 characters long string, command line displayed). Problem arises when retrieval is done, Database SW will look for Integer value from the field but gets some non-supported values. (Hence error).

May be my question now shifted to the one in brackets in fore mentioned paragraph ? Is it true (because it proved like that to me) or Is there other reasons ?